# nokogiri: Get shortcut icon from a page

Tags: ruby, icons, nokogiri

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@smotchkkiss is correct for most cases. By and large, if a website provides an icon, it's where he said it would be. However, it isn't *required* to be there. The favicon can be specified via `link` tags in the document itself. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Standardization_and_implementation) for more details on how the standards say it *should* be done.

Answer (score 0):

To use nokogiri, you need to grab the following link element: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/so/favicon.ico">` (this was taken from this site).